# can't able to access the value inside it says undefined

Tags: javascript

```js
function randomNumber1() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}
var a;
var b;
const image1 = document.querySelector(".img1");
image1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let random1 = randomNumber1();
  image1.src = `/images/dice${random1}.png`;
  a = random1;
});
console.log(a)

const image2 = document.querySelector(".img2");
image2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let random2 = randomNumber1();
  image2.src = `/images/dice${random2}.png`;
});
console.log(b);

let h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
```

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.dice {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  background-color: #393E46;
}

h1 {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  text-shadow: 5px 0 #232931;
  font-size: 8rem;
  color: #4ECCA3;
}

p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #4ECCA3;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

img {
  width: 80%;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 5%;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Refresh Me</h1>

  <div class="dice">
    <p>Player 1</p>
    <img class="img1" src="/images/dice6.png">
  </div>

  <div class="dice">
    <p>Player 2</p>
    <img class="img2" src="/images/dice6.png">
  </div>

</div>
```

```
function randomNumber1(){
  return  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}
var a;
var b;
const image1 = document.querySelector(".img1");
image1.addEventListener('click', ()=>{   
     let random1 = randomNumber1();
      image1.src = `/images/dice${random1}.png`;
      a = random1;
});
   console.log(a)

const image2 = document.querySelector(".img2");
image1.addEventListener('click', ()=>{   
   let random2 = randomNumber1();
    image2.src = `/images/dice${random2}.png`;
  });
console.log(b);
```

I tried to create a dice game in js i wanted a way to score this random value to show who wins and score for player but i wasn't able to access the value inside even though i declared the variable outside

so far I've tried to access the value in different ways like declaring the value in global scope and i found out that let and const is block scoped and tried to use var but I'm still wasn't able to figure it out

Comment: Can you kindly add the HTML as well or make a [mre] using a Snippet here... Are you loading the JS after the element or before?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO. You should add your markup too. Use the snippet tool in the edit toolbar `[<>]` to create a [mcve].

Comment: `addEventListener` does just that. It adds an event listener. It doesn't wait for the event to occur before it continues. If that were the case, you had to click on `image1` before you could ever add an event listener to `image2`. `console.log(a)` is executed before the function you pass to the event listener which sets the value of `a`.

Comment: how can i access the value after the execution

Comment: Check @Ivar's comment above, that's the reason. You can't get the value of the random one until and unless the click action has been executed.

Comment: @NikhilShetty What should be your flow? If you wanna access after the click action has been done, put the `console.log` inside the function.

Comment: i know that i can able to access the value inside the scope in eventlistener . but i can't calculate the value and judge who is the winner

Comment: @Articmountain Check my answer, I understood what you wanted... 

Comment: Keep in mind the _minimal_ part of the [mcve] guidance. If the question isn't reliant on the styling you can remove the CSS block. You also have your function definitions twice, and haven't actually specified which variable you can't access—it looks like `a` and `b` but just saying "the value" is unclear

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the code (random num gen) doesn't execute. You can do something like this:

```js
function randomNumber1() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}
var a;
var b;
const image1 = document.querySelector(".img1");
image1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let random1 = randomNumber1();
  image1.src = `/images/dice${random1}.png`;
  a = random1;
  console.log(a);
});

const image2 = document.querySelector(".img2");
image1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let random2 = randomNumber1();
  image2.src = `/images/dice${random2}.png`;
  b = random2;
  console.log(b);
});


let h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
```

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.dice {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  background-color: #393E46;
}

h1 {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  text-shadow: 5px 0 #232931;
  font-size: 8rem;
  color: #4ECCA3;
}

p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #4ECCA3;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

img {
  width: 80%;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 5%;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Refresh Me</h1>

  <div class="dice">
    <p>Player 1</p>
    <img class="img1" src="/images/dice6.png">
  </div>

  <div class="dice">
    <p>Player 2</p>
    <img class="img2" src="/images/dice6.png">
  </div>

</div>
```

This will show in the console, the values! Or maybe you can make a function to call it and check whenever you want to... Also remember, you have to use `image2.addEventListener` not `image1.addEventListener` again. See below:

```js
function randomNumber1() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}
var a;
var b;

function checkValues(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log({
    a,
    b
  });
}

const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener('click', checkValues);

const image1 = document.querySelector(".img1");
image1.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let random1 = randomNumber1();
  image1.src = `/images/dice${random1}.png`;
  a = random1;
  console.log(a);
});

const image2 = document.querySelector(".img2");
image2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let random2 = randomNumber1();
  image2.src = `/images/dice${random2}.png`;
  b = random2;
  console.log(b);
});


let h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
```

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.dice {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

body {
  background-color: #393E46;
}

h1 {
  margin: 30px;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  text-shadow: 5px 0 #232931;
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #4ECCA3;
}

p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #4ECCA3;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

img {
  width: 80%;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 5%;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="btn">Check Values!</button>

  <h1>Refresh Me</h1>

  <div class="dice">
    <p>Player 1</p>
    <img class="img1" src="/images/dice6.png">
  </div>

  <div class="dice">
    <p>Player 2</p>
    <img class="img2" src="/images/dice6.png">
  </div>

</div>
```